# JavaScript Regex start of string clarification + str.replace()

Tags: javascript, regex, palindrome

got a question about the start of string regex anchor tag `^`.
I was trying to sanitize a string to check if it's a palindrome and found a solution to use regex but couldn't wrap my head around the explanations I found for the start of string anchor tag:

#### To my understanding:

`^` denotes that whatever expression that follows must match, starting from the beginning of the string.

#### Question:

Why then is there a difference between the two output below:

1)

```
let x = 'A man, a plan, a canal: Panama';
const re = new RegExp(/[^a-z]/, 'gi');
console.log(x.replace(re, '*'));
```

Output: `A*man**a*plan**a*canal**Panama`

VS.

2)

```
let x = 'A man, a plan, a canal: Panama';
const re = new RegExp(/[a-z]/, 'gi');
console.log(x.replace(re, '*'));
```

Output: `* ***, * ****, * *****: ******`

VS.

3)

```
let x = 'A man, a plan, a canal: Panama';
const re = new RegExp(/^[a-z]/, 'gi');
console.log(x.replace(re, '*'));
```

Output: `* man, a plan, a canal: Panama`

Please let me know if my explanation for each of the case above is off:

1) *Confused about this one*. If it matches a character class of `[a-z]` case insensitive + global find, with start of string anchor `^` denoting that it must match at the start of each string, should it not return all the words in the sentence? Since each word is a match of `[a-z]` insensitive characters that occurs at the start of each string per global find iteration?

(i.e.

- finds "A" at the start
- then on the next iteration, it should start search on the remaining string " man"
- finds a space...and moves on to search "man"?
- and so on and so forth...

Q: Why does it then when I call `replace` does it only targets the non alpha stuff? Should I in this case be treating `^` as inverting `[a-z]`?

2) This seems pretty straight forward, finds all occurrence of `[a-z]`and replaces them with the start. Inverse case of 1)??

3) *Also confused about this one*. I'm not sure how this is different from 1).

`/^[a-z]/gi` to me means:  "starting at the start of the string being looked at, match all alpha characters, case insensitive. Repeat for global find".

Compared to:

1) `/[^a-z]/gi` to me means: "match all character class that starts each line with alpha character. case insensitive, repeat search for global find."

To mean they mean exactly the same @_@. Please let me know how my understanding is off for the above cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your first expression `[^a-z]` matches anything other than an alphabetic, lower case letter, therefore that's why when you replace with `*` all the special characters such as whitespace, commas and colons are replaced.
- Your second expression `[a-z]` matches any alphabetic, lower case letter, therefore the special characters mentioned are not replaced by `*`.
- Your third expression `^[a-z]` matches a alphabetic, lower case letter at the start of the string, therefore only the first letter is replaced by `*`.

For the first two expressions, the global flag `g` ensures that all characters that match the specified pattern, regardless of their position in the string, are replaced. For the third pattern however, since `^` anchors the pattern at the beginning of the string, only the first letter is replaced.

As you mentioned, the `i` flag ensures case insensitivity, so that all three patterns operate on both lower and upper case alphabetic letters, from `a` to `z` and `A` to `Z`.

The character `^` therefore has two meanings:

- It negates characters in a character set.
- It asserts position at the start of string.

Comment: Ah thanks for a quick and thoughtful response. I will note for future case that `^` hold two meanings.

Answer (score 1):

> ^ denotes that whatever expression that follows must match, starting from the beginning of the string.

That's only when it's the first thing in the regex; it has other purposes when used elsewhere:

```
/[^a-z]/gi
```

In the above regex, the `^` does *not* indicate anchoring the match to the beginning of a string; it inverts the rest of the contents of the `[]` -- so the above regex will match any single character *except* a-z.  Since you're using the `g` flag it will repeat that match for all characters in the string.

```
/[a-z]/gi
```

The above is not inverted, so will match a single instance of any character from a-z (and again because of the `g` flag will repeat to match all of those instances.)

```
/^[a-z]/gi
```

In this last example, the caret anchors the match to the beginning of the string; the bracketed portion will match any single a-z character.  The `g` flag is still in use, so the regex would try to continue matching more characters later in the string -- but none of them except the first one will will meet the anchored-to-start requirement, so this will end up matching only the first character (if it's within a-z), exactly as if the `g` flag was not in use.

(When used anywhere in a regex other than the start of the regex or the start of a `[]` group, the `^` will be treated as a literal `^`.)

If you're trying to detect palindromes, you'll want to remove everything except letter characters (and will probably want to convert everything to the same letter case, instead of having to detect that "P" == "p":)

```js
const isPalindrome = function(input) {
  let str = input.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'');
  return str === str.split('').reverse().join('')
}

console.log(isPalindrome("Able was I, ere I saw Elba!"))

console.log(isPalindrome("No, it never propagates if I set a ”gap“ or prevention."))

console.log(isPalindrome("Are we not pure? “No, sir!” Panama’s moody Noriega brags. “It is garbage!” Irony dooms a man –– a prisoner up to new era."))

console.log(isPalindrome("Taco dog is not a palindrome."))
```

Comment: Yeah, did not know that `^` held another meaning when used inside of character sets `[]`. Thanks for the thorough explanation.